# cannot list resources from all resource group in a subscription using az cli

Tags: bash, azure

Is there a way to make a az CLI call to list the deployment group from all resource groups in a subscription?
I'm trying to create a bash script to get the deployment groups in a given subscription but no luck. Here is what i've tried.

1. `rgs=$(az group list --subscription $subscription_id -o json | jq -r '.[] | .name')`, i'm passing subscription as  input parameter.
2. `az deployment group list --resource-group $rgs --subscription $subscription_id  --query '[].{Name:name, ResourceGroup:resourceGroup, Timestamp:properties.timestamp}' -o table`

It gives me `invalid argument` error.

It looks like the resource group variable that i use does not recognize. not sure if there is any other way.

So tried the following.

```
rg_list=($rgs)
for rg in "${rg_list[@]}"
do
  az deployment group list --resource-group $rgs --subscription $subscription_id  --query '[].{Name:name, ResourceGroup:resourceGroup, Timestamp:properties.timestamp}' -o table
done
```

after adding the loop it works but the loop goes on to check every resource group in the subscription to display the result but the actual goal is to get the deployment group from all the resource groups in a single attempt without having to go on a loop

Comment: Probably not, at least using "az deployment group list" as it expects a single resource group, not a list of groups. I think you will have to loop for this.

Comment: Thanks @ewramner, you're right i had to loop it to get the results and few changes have been made and now i have a csv formatted file with name,resourcegroup, timestamp is there a way we could also print the subscription id as the last column. I have been trying various option with no luck. So the columns should look like below...

```Name  ResourceGroup TimeStamp Subscription_ID```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the expected result by using the `awk` command. Thanks